# Differential geometry: $|\alpha(t)|=c\ne 0 \iff \langle \alpha(t),\alpha'(t)\rangle = 0,\forall t\in I$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha: I\to \Bbb R^3$ be a regular para curve. I want to prove that:

$|\alpha(t)|=c\ne 0 \iff \langle \alpha(t),\alpha'(t)\rangle = 0,\forall t\in I$

Now $|\alpha(t)|=c\ne 0$ means that this traces some subset or an entire path on the surface of a sphere radius $c$, in some direction. I can see that then the tangent to any point on the sphere is definitely an orthogonal plane(it's flat on the surface). What I can't do is prove either direction mathematically.

$(\implies)$ $|\alpha(t)|=c\ne0$ gives us $x(t)^2+y(t)^2+z(t)^2=c^2$ which is our surface transversal as we know. No idea how to get the orthogonality.

Actually the fact that $xx'+yy'+zz'=0$ looks like it implies that whatever was nonzero in $\alpha$ is zero in $\alpha'$, so then $\alpha'=0$

But the definition of orthogonality comes from nonzero vectors, so I don't know.

Comment: Hint: what's the derivative of $|\alpha(t)|^2$?

Comment: You've got an answer, but note that "$xx' + yy' + zz' = 0$" says precisely that the dot product of the position $(x, y, z)$ and the velocity $(x', y', z')$ is zero, i.e., these vectors are orthogonal. (It looks as if you were interpreting the left-hand side term by term, which is not productive.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $|\alpha(t)| = \sqrt{\langle \alpha(t), \alpha(t) \rangle} = c$, so $$\langle \alpha(t), \alpha(t) \rangle = c^2.$$

What happens when you derive both sides with respect to $t$?

Comment: $\langle\alpha(t),\alpha'(t)\rangle+\langle\alpha'(t),\alpha(t)\rangle=0\implies$ they negate eachother, or both are zero, but they are equal right, so then they must both be zero, and that solves going to the right, is that right?

Comment: Yes, both summands on the LHS of your equation are equal because of *symmetry* of the inner product, so they must both be zero. You can basically go along the exact same chain of thought - but backwards - to get the other direction of the statement you want to prove.

Comment: Thanks very muchly, helped a bunch.